# Create I Frame out of P and B frames

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-encoding

I've written a C++ converter based on FFMpeg which can receive a link to hls-stream and convert it into local .mp4 video. So far, so good, converter works like a charm, no questions about that.

**PROBLEM:** No matter what input source I'm providing to the converter, at the end of convertation I need to receive video with key-frames ONLY. I need such video due to perfect seeking forward and reverse.

It's a well-known fact that subsidiary video frames (P and B) dependent on their owner-frame (I frame), because this frame contains full pixel map. According to that, we can recreate a I frame for each P and B frame by merging their data with their I frame. That's why such ffmpeg command `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 output%4d.jpg` works.

**QUESTION:** How can I implement an algorithm of merging of frames in order to recreate Key-frames ONLY video at the end? What kind of quirks I need to know about merging datas of `AVPacket`s?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't merge AVPackets like that. When re-encoding, set keyint to 1.

Comment: Thank you for your response, @Gyan. You 100% and absolutely can recreate key frame by merging frame data. Maybe not merging `AVPacket`, maybe merging `AVFrame`. I just don't know what is the exact way, that's why I'm asking this. And setting keyint to 1 absolutely doesn't make a frame Keyframe.

Comment: AVFrames in ffmpeg are fully decoded frames, so there's no 'keyframe' or otherwise. AVframe flag key_frame is set by the decoder and is historical info. With keyint=1, I get all IDR frames.with x264 encoding.

Comment: Could you explain what you meant by "keyint=1"?

Comment: Private option of the encoder; on the command line set using `-x264-params keyint=1`. In API, I believe you need to use av_opt_set; alternatively, you can set gop_size in the codec context to 1, which the x264 wrapper will then pick up.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot "merge" P and B-frames of a compressed stream (e.g. with H.264 codec), to obtain I-frames.

What ffmpeg does with

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 output%4d.jpg
```

is decoding each frame (thus it needs to start from an I-frame, then decode all subsequent P and B-frames in the stream), and compress them back to JPEG and output a JPEG image for each frame in the original input stream.

If you want to convert an input stream with P/B frames to an intra-only stream (with all I-frames), you need to **[transcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcoding)** the stream.
That means decode all frames from the original stream and encode them back to an intra-only stream.