# Is it possible to undo temporal compression by reconstructing I-frames from B or P frames?

Tags: image, opencv, video, ffmpeg, compression

Is it possible to convert P or B frames back into I-frames?

This post suggest its possible via transcoding, but I do not understand the solution at all.

[Create I Frame out of P and B frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345831/create-i-frame-out-of-p-and-b-frames)

I am trying to take a video with I/P/B frames and reconstruct it to a I/I/I, like a MotionJPEG video.

Comment: You are describing transcoding. What do you not understand about it?

Comment: @szatmary Thank you. Can you provide any documentation or tutorials on how to do this exact problem? I can't seem to find any.

Comment: I dont think I can, at least not to satisfy you. Because when I google "ffmpeg transcode iframe only" I get many many good example. So either these examples do not work for you, and you then have failed to explain why they do not work for you, Or there is something you fundamentally do not understand about transcoding, in with case you need to take the time to read and understand. I can not do either of those things for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will extract all frames to PNGs, that way you technically have only i-frames.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 frames/%08d.png
```

If you want a video instead, re-encode to ProRes for example:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:v prores_ks video.mov
```

...as ProRes only has i-frames.

Or, if you want MJPEG:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:v mjpeg video.mov
```